# Symfony2: how to access second page?

Tags: symfony, web

I'm new on Symfony, so the code in some documents might not make sense. Anyways, I'm making a website and so far, I made two pages on it (one's called "web" i think and the other's called "terms"). However, I don't know how to access the second page in terms of routing. Here's my code:

**1. TermsController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\WebBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class TermsController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($some)
    {
        return $this->render('AcmeWebBundle:Terms:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

**2. /WebBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml**

web:

```
pattern:  /web
defaults: { _controller: AcmeWebBundle:Default:index }
```

_terms:

```
pattern: /web/terms
resource: "@AcmeWebBundle/Controller/TermsController.php"
```

I'm supposed to access the second page through http://***/app_dev.php/web/terms, but I get errors.

*** = localhost

Comment: why you didn't use defaults: { _controller: AcmeWebBundle:Terms:index } for _term in route ?

Comment: I tried that. Actually, if I delete the "_terms" section of routing.yml and just keep the "web" routing, then everything works perfectly fine. If i add the "_terms" section into routing.yml, then I can't access both "/web" and "/web/terms"

Comment: first insert  _terms: section  and then web: section

Comment: I did that and it showed some sort of improvement. It took me to the Symfony error page instead of some other error page. I got this critical error: CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "Controller "Acme\WebBundle\Controller\TermsController::indexAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$some" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one)." at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 2093

Comment: if you dont need $some just delete it from indexAction($some) from TermsController.php

Comment: ok now it's saying that it can't find a template for it. So I'm going to try and make a template for it...

Comment: Ok it's still not working. CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "Unable to find template "AcmeWebBundle:Terms:index.html.php"." at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/TwigEngine.php line 128

Comment: do you have index.html.twig file in Acme/WebBundle/Resources/views/Terms/index.html.twig  ??

Comment: Oh actually it worked!! It's just that I used "Terms" for everything but the folder name was "AP Terms". I changed the folder name to "Terms" and it worked! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

If the TermsController's indexAction is exactly the same as you specified then why you use $same parameter? You getting an error exactly because of that.

You should ether remove $some from indexAction in TermsController or specify default value for $some in your route configuration. Something like that:

```
_terms:
   path: /web/terms/{some}
   defaults:
       _controller: AcmeWebBundle:Terms:index
       some: ''
```

or if you will not use route parameter:

```
_terms:
   path: /web/terms
   defaults:
       _controller: AcmeWebBundle:Terms:index
```

You can check [Symfony2 routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html) documentation.